# How do I connect to Directus dashboard once site is deployed?

Tags: content-management-system, admin, headless, directus

I've just createed a React site using a the selfhosted CMS headless Directus.
I'm not sure how to proceed to get in the dashboard.
Site is deployed on Netlify, not sure if I need to configure something and I can't find doc on it.
Thanks

I have tried example.com/admin, admin/login...
Set up project URL in local dashboard then updated my site